# Android blocking API calls to localhost

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

iOS and browser API calls are working fine, but the Android simulator blocks/removes the API url and blocks calls to localhost. Calls on the production HTTPS server work fine.

CORS has been implemented and is working on every HTTP request.

[image]

How do I allow calls to non-HTTPS localhost on Cordova Android 6.3.0 and Ionic 3.19?

I have permitted the following in config.xml

```
 <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
```

Comment: have u add this permission on manifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-run-android-works-but-apk-does-not-access-internet/3867/15

Answer (score 0):

Are you running ionic cordova emulate --address localhost ?

Ionic makes some network assumptions.

Also do you have the https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/ installed?